# This RP accent makes me confused and mad

Tags: pronunciation, speech, phonetics, accent

I'm trying to choose between RP and my current conventional accents/pronunciations.

For already two weeks I've been looking for some proves that RP is worth something and it's well-accepted everywhere. But I failed. I've only got some proves that no one uses complete RP or even partially. People, especially native speakers, do not like it.

So now when I look up some new words I can't choose which pronunciation to pick up. Like here:

> [a tourist](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tourist?q=tourist): conventional - /ˈtʊərɪst/, RP - /ˈtɔːrɪst/

Can you recommend which option to choose? Which pronunciation is more relevant or better for ESL students?

Comment: When you say 'people do not like it', you are probably referring to what the article recommended by Stuart below calls 'conventional RP' - the old-fashioned upper-class English accent, also used by BBC announcers in the earlier 20th century, which is rarely heard nowadays and is much mocked. Even the Queen no longer speaks with quite the same accent as she did when she was young. What the dictionary labels as RP is _not_ this kind of accent.

Comment: Off-topic as opinion-based on ELU, but so important and English-orientated I'll not close vote. (2) _Listen to 'University Challenge'_ (etc) (record and get rid as appropriate), ignore the obviously peripheral accents and questions, and get a feel for the spread of accents left uncorrected by tutors/editors. (3) Roughly copy the one/s you like. (4) Look up ('listen up'?) words where necessary and choose the pronunciation you like. (5) Try to be consistent within your chosen speech. (1) Don't worry about having to / being free to adjust; I had to look up 'ceanothus' a few years back.

Comment: That second pronunciation of *tourist* in your link doesn't correspond with the IPA. I hear it as [ˈtʊrɪst] and not [ˈtɔːrɪst]. That's a real oversight on their part. But [ˈtɔːrɪst] is a perfectly good British pronunciation (which you can also hear in some regions of America).

Comment: Accent reveals background. RP is fancy. If someone from, say, Siberia is looking to take on a good English accent, is it really a good idea to imitate a fancy sound and present a background that is so far from your own? *(Ignore comment as coming from a New Yorker who is an accent lover.)*

Comment: There's regional variations of English in every country, with some are more accepted than others. So just pick a popular (non-stigmatized) regional pronunciation and listen to people who use it. Bust out Youtube. Away you go, right?

Comment: *Can you recommend which option to choose?* Choose the same accent as the persons that you speak with the most, i.e. those who are in your social circle.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, the phoneme /ʊə/ is being lost from RP. Now, it's mainly older, conservative speakers who use the pronunciation [ʊə]. In one-syllable words, younger RP speakers generally merge it /ɔː/, so *poor, tour, moor, sure* are homonyms with *pour, tore, more, shore*.   [See this webpage](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/cardiff.htm), which also details several other changes that are happening to the English language.

For ESL students, this means that you can totally dispense with learning the phoneme /ʊə/, which I would assume makes things easier. (Although in a few words like *rural*, it gets replaced by vowels other than /ɔː/, so if you want perfect pronunciation, you need to be a little careful.)

Changes don't happen only in English; in any language spoken by a large number of people, sounds are always changing. For example, the reason that Beijing used to be spelled Peking is that the middle consonant used to be [k] rather than [tɕ]. And these changes don't happen all at once, so during the transition period different people use different pronunciations.